# Solar vs Planetary

Tags: solar-system

Am I correct in thinking that although our solar system is a planetary system we are the only ‘solar system’ in our universe simply because of the name of our sun?

Comment: call it stellar system, if you want to make the distinction Sun vs. other stars. If not... use stellar system and solar system interchangeably. There's one Sun. But several suns.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Our Planetary system is the only "Solar System", because it is the only one officially called as "Solar system". A Planetary system or Stellar system is generally named after the star, Example: Proxima Centauri System, TOI 270 system etc, and our system's naming is similar to those since the term "Solar" means something that related to our star Sun (obviously not any other stars when it comes to the terms used).

> Our solar system is just one specific planetary system—a star with planets orbiting around it. Our planetary system is the only one officially called “solar system,” but astronomers have discovered more than 3,200 other stars with planets orbiting them in our galaxy. That’s just how many we’ve found so far. There are likely to be many more planetary systems out there waiting to be discovered! Our Sun is just one of about 200 billion stars in our galaxy. That gives scientists plenty of places to hunt for exoplanets, or planets outside our solar system. But our capabilities have only recently progressed to the point where astronomers can actually find such planets.

Read more: [NASA](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/other-solar-systems/en/#:%7E:text=The%20Short%20Answer%3A,with%20planets%20orbiting%20around%20it.)

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of that NASA page. The terms "solar system" and "Solar System" are very different, just like "moon" and "Moon". The capitalization makes all the different. The last sentence of that page says "Who knows? One day, by studying **exoplanets and distant solar systems**, astronomers hope to answer the intriguing question: Is there life elsewhere in our galaxy?" We are not the only solar system, even NASA calls the other ones "solar systems", just not "The Solar System".

Comment: @uhoh I definitely Agree with your point. But if I understood the question correctly the OP is focusing on the naming, and not terms.

Comment: ya I saw it the other way, but I can certainly see how it could be how you see it. Hopefully we'll find out at some point :-)

Comment: @uhoh. I have done some analysis, The term solar system generally refer to our *planetary/stellar system*. And People in Physics SE do feel the same. I think there is no disambiguation to the term solar system.